# missing CID prefix in CXF SOAP request with attachments

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

I'm trying to call a Web Service with SoapWithAttachments method. My client-side software is JAVA and it uses Apache CXF (v2.5.11) to generate the classes from the WSDL.

When I run it, I print the SOAP request in the log and see that the CID prefix ("cid:") for referencing the attachment is missing. There is the correct content-id of the attachment, but the prefix is missing. Finally, the server returns me a "empty attachment" error.

There is an example of the SOAP request that my software prints:

```
ID: 1
Address: ****
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="uuid:5210b5e9-ee88-4b88-9330-f95ee62bb28e"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["****"]}
Payload: --uuid:5210b5e9-ee88-4b88-9330-f95ee62bb28e
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <metodo>
        <documento>
            <contenido href="8849d331-555b-4ab4-b90d-6ff0996cadcc@apache.org"/>
            <hash>0p9oDCPlhlxNemvtT5tj6e46SHdPWLOxTi1sLJBeCz4=</hash>
        </documento>
    </metodo>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--uuid:5210b5e9-ee88-4b88-9330-f95ee62bb28e
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <8849d331-555b-4ab4-b90d-6ff0996cadcc@apache.org>

%PDF-1.4
%????
2 0 obj
<</Length 76/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x?+?r
?26S?00I?2P?5?1??
?B?4<Rsr???rR
?JS?
@?]C????
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Parent 3 0 R/Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 1 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ITXT(2.1.7)/Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[4 0 R]>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Producer(iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT)/ModDate(D:20150327140035+01'00')/CreationDate(D:20150327140035+01'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000314 00000 n
0000000015 00000 n
0000000402 00000 n
0000000157 00000 n
0000000465 00000 n
0000000510 00000 n
trailer
<</Root 5 0 R/ID [<5d256b5d87f178862dd33943e65718e8><ecd829bf4e1d355aef68138d0de19d76>]/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>>
startxref
632
%%EOF

--uuid:5210b5e9-ee88-4b88-9330-f95ee62bb28e--
```

Notice that the attachment does exist, and it has a correct Content-id (I supose), and the SOAP request references it in a apparently correct name. But the "cid:" prefix is still missing and I don`t have idea how to add it.

On the other hand, if I copy and paste the SOAP request from here to SOAP-UI, and add the "cid:" prefix, and add the attachment with the same Content-id, the request runs correctly.

Comment: hello friend, have you found the solution? can you please paste here as anwser, im on same boat

Comment: have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185284/3570413